# extract zlib file in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, compression, zlib

When downloading data from a server thats compressed using zlib, I was wondering what steps are needed to take to uncompress and save to core data

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to retrieve the file off the network. That can handle gzip which is likely what the data coming off the network is compressed with.

If you'd prefer to roll your own, take a look at this [zlib category](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory) on NSData: Has worked well for me in the past and likely does what you'll need.

You'll also need to add -lz to the "other linker flags" build setting

Comment: zlib category link seems to be broken.. can you please update it?