# Is there a native zip or gzip decompression function in ios available?

Tags: ios, compression

I do know that there are some libraries (ZLib, MiniZip, etc.) to manage the task.

However, I am looking for an iOs or system library based solution. The URL transport protocol has embedded transport compression of GZIP,
so it would be interesting if anybody managed to find a public accessible interface of the iOS library.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066965/extract-zlib-file-in-ios

zlib is available - at least!

Comment: I would like to decompress downloaded files, which are already compressed on the server) for performance reasons. And I want to make use of system libraries not to reinvent the wheel. The hint from TheReallSA is good, especially to NSData extensions. Now I just have to find out how to get it up and running. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use NSURLConnection the data you receive will have been unzipped for you.

Comment: Yes, it seems that this solution is the easiest variant. I just had to tweak the webserver to use Transfer-Encoding. However, the hint from ThReallSA to embed the library was the bit i were looking for. Sometimes one should think too much.